# React Router place component in a particular div while routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Using react router how do i place a component in a particular div ? Currently it renders below the last rendered component at the end of the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned you are using react-router v4, You can place the Route component anywhere in your component, nested routes can be written within the child component

For instance

Say you have a component App like

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
              <div>
                  <Navbar/>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route path ="/roster" component={Roster}
              </div>
         )
    }
}
```

Now say if the Roster component contains nested Routes you can place the Route component anywhere you want to render the children Routes

```
const Roster = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/roster" component={ListComp} />
        <div className="rosterDetails">
            <Route exact path="/roster/:rosterId" component={Details} />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```